# Какой формат лучше и проще использовать для рендеринга итогового документа из java, rtf или doc?

Tags: java, doc, rtf

У нас система документооборота, нужно рендерить итоговый документ и отсылать на почту. Это печатная форма контракта. То есть есть шаблон, куда нужно вставлять поля.

Этот шаблон загружает Админ, то есть от него поступает файлы с разметкой:
Здравствуйте, `${name}`.

И если клиент регистрируется, то получает письмо с доком, тип которого создал админ. Это я к тому, что документы добавляются админом, но не программистом. Html работает плохо, т.к. учить админа верске не вариант.

Спасибо!

Comment: лучше использовать pdf

Answer (score 1):

PDF или HTML. Однозначно не DOC и, скорее всего, вы имеете ввиду RTF в нотации Microsoft, который однозначно читается только Wordpad или Word и выглядит совершенно непотребно в любой другой программе. Почему не DOC? Представьте себе я такой крутой клиент вашей фирмы только что купил новенький MacBook Pro, регистрируюсь у вас где-то там и тут, бах!, мне приходит письмо в формате Microsoft Word. Вопрос - я конечно всё бросаю и бегу в магазин покупать Microsoft Office (тыщ десять кажется в рублях) или посылаю вашу распрекрасную компанию с вашими дурацкими письмами сами понимаете куда? Поставьте вашего Admina перед вопросом - или он учится красиво оформлять письма, например в HTML (пусть WYSIWYNG редактор себе найдёт), или письма отправляются Plain Text.

Comment: Отчётность в html - это что-то новенькое.

Comment: @Qwertiy , как я понял из вопроса речь идёт не об отчётности, а об рассылке писем, подтверждающих регистрацию клиента в каком-то сервисе. Также не вижу ничего плохого в формировании отчётности в HTML формате - такие файлы легко формировать, легко прочесть, а при желании замечательно открываются в Microsoft Excel или Libre Ofice (OpenOffice) Calc.

Comment: А я понял, что есть какая-то система, которая формирует отчёт и как вложение рассылает его кому надо.

Answer (score 0):

Pdf- практически везде будет выглядеть одинаково! Можно и подпись наложить и печать если требуется,и есть права на использования